# tvOS shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource requesting the same resources

Tags: avplayer, avurlasset, tvos10

I'm implementing `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` handler for `AVPlayer`/`AVURLAsset` HLS videos and found a weird behavior in tvOS.

As I see it could request the same resources multiple times, including "root" manifest, second-level manifests and segments (and I'm talking not about multiple quality switches, it's requesting exactly the same resources).

In the same time, each request are served with my code well enough – video is playing good. 
Also, exactly the same code is working fine in iOS – no duplicated requests.

In which cases `AVURLAsset`/`AVAssetResourceLoader` could request the same resources multiple times in tvOS?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem
I can add that I'm using the apple sample app

```
public func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
  print("\(#function) was called in AssetLoaderDelegate with loadingRequest: \(loadingRequest)")
  var ret : Bool = true
  ret =  shouldLoadOrRenewRequestedResource(resourceLoadingRequest: loadingRequest)
  return ret
}
```

This is the debug print i get:

> resourceLoader(_:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:) was called
>   in AssetLoaderDelegate with loadingRequest:
>    { URL:
>   skd://817015000008100f172b492d3b25f5dda31c59d090b21000 }, request
>   ID = 3, content information request =
>   AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest: 0x14f6dd070, content
>   type = "(null)", content length = 0, byte range access supported = NO,
>   disk caching permitted = NO, renewal date = (null), data request =
>   AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest: 0x14f67ae50, requested offset = 0,
>   requested length = 9223372036854775807, requests all data to end of
>   resource = YES, current offset = 0

I can see each time the value `request ID` in the print is different

Comment: If the master manifest contains the #EXT-X-SESSION-KEY key i will be called also on tvos one once

Comment: hi, could you share the apple sample app please?